# Updating something in a database with a php file

Tags: php, mysql

Hello iam working on a game on unity3d and i have a login/register system that have a database so i have these level thing i want to save in to the users database, just for testing i have created this php file:

```
<?PHP

$username = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$con = mysql_connect("host","user","password") or ("Cannot         connect!"  . mysql_error());
if (!$con)
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("database" , $con) or die ("could not load the database" .     mysql_error());
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username`='".$username."'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($check);
if($username == null)
{
    die ("You are not allowed to access this site! \n");
}
else
{
    if ($numrows == 0)
    {
            die ("Username does not exist \n");
    }
    else
    {
            $pass = md5($pass);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check))
            {
                    if ($pass == $row['pass'])
                    {
                            die("saved-SUCCESS");
                            $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE users SET level='2' WHERE id='1'";
                            //$SQL = "UPDATE users SET level = '2' WHERE id = 1";
                    }
                    else
                            die("Password is wrong \n");
            }
    }
}

?>
```

it does says "saved-SUCCESS" in unity3d so that means this:

```
$sqlUpdate = "UPDATE users SET level='2' WHERE id='1'";
```

should work but it doesent
also i have tryed this:

```
$SQL = "UPDATE users SET level = '2' WHERE id = 1";
```

but it doesent work either
here is a picture of the user with id 1:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o7aw.png
and here is a picture of the structur tab:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtDgA.png
and yes my table is named users :)

Comment: you exit, before the query is run

Comment: **Please** stop using `mysql_*` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not executing your second query but only printing `saved-SUCCES`

```
$sqlUpdate = "UPDATE users SET level='Rune' WHERE id='1'";
mysql_query($sqlUpdate);
die("saved-SUCCESS"); //then exit.
```

As side note i would advise thta your code is highly vulnerable mo mysql injection, you should use prepared statments either with [**`PDO`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [**`mysqli`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php), also [**`mysql_*`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) api are deprecated and soon will be no longer mantained.